# how to put multiple images after resizing two in a row using magick in php

Tags: php, imagemagick

i have to make a pdf consisting of the multiple images on a single A4 sheet.
for which i have used magick but was unable to do that. the library is output the images one on a single page. put what i actually want is to put multiple or atleast 8 images on a single sheet consisting of 2 in each row.

the code i have used is as :

```
$image1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/project_name/admin/qrcode/2/103746768-Qrcode53.png';
$image2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/project_name/admin/qrcode/2/105443618-Qrcode34.png';
$image3 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/project_name/admin/qrcode/2/109305628-Qrcode2.png';
$images = array($image1,$image2,$image3);
$new_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/project_name/admin/qrcode/2/combined.pdf';
$pdf = new Imagick($images);
$pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
$pdf->writeImages($new_path,true);
```

Comment: Try TCPDF and dump a formatted HTML, with all your images. Not only you'd be able to dump more images to the same page, but you'd have the ability to format your PDF layout in a better way.

Comment: Look at `montage` here... http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.montageimage.php

Comment: @MarkSetchell this one helped me..thanks

Comment: Also checkout [`Imagick::appendImages`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php) for stacking images by rows & columns.

Comment: can we add text with the images with magick?

Comment: @emcconville this one is adding image one below the other not the manner i want.